# Non trivial $f$ such that $\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx=a_n\pi+b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, examples-counterexamples, pi

> I need a non trivial function $f(x)$ such that $$\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx=a_n\pi+b_n$$ where $a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

We know that $$\pi=4\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx$$

By Binomial theorem for rational index $$\pi= 4\int_0^1 \sum_{r=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{r} x^{2r}\ dx$$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit**

If $f(x)=\sin^{-1} x$ then [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+x%5En+sin%5E%28-1%29+x+from+0+to+1)  $$\int_0^1 x^n \sin^{-1} x \ dx= c_n \pi +d_n$$ but $c_n,d_n\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: You want this to be true for all natural numbers $n$?  Do you have any reason to think such an $f$ exists?
Well, an integer multiple of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ certainly won't work because that would produce rationals for odd $n$ and rationals times $\pi$ for even $n$, with those rationals $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ since $\int_0^1 x^n f(x)\; dx \to 0$.

Comment: With $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$ $$\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx=a_n\pi+b_n+c_n \log(2)$$ would be simple for any $n$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But the coefficients are not integers. For instance see for $n=1$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+x+tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29+from+0+to+1

Comment: Sorry ! They are rational.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry , but I need integral coefiicients

Comment: Can you give some context on why do you need such a specific function?

Comment: The integral tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. So, this would result in an integral that approximated $\pi$, because we would need $a_n$ and $b_n$ of opposite signs such that $-b_n/a_n \to \pi$ as $n\to\infty$. This seems like a very difficult task, see [here](http://educ.jmu.edu/~lucassk/Papers/more%20on%20pi.pdf).

Comment: @P.S.Dester Thank you so much for your insights.